# New sessionid in every request

Tags: django, reactjs, http, cookies, axios

I am creating my django react app. I would like to make authentication via Cookie just like in Django oscar documentation.

But when i send my post request i get a new session id with every request.
I am using axios with credentials.

Its my **base.py**

```
 MIDDLEWARE = [

'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
 ]
 CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
 CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
 CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
"https://example.com",
"https://sub.example.com",
"http://127.0.0.1:8000",
"http://localhost:3000",
"http://localhost:8000",
"http://127.0.0.1:9000",
"127.0.0.1"
]
```

And this is my Post requests

```
import axios from "axios"
import Bar from './Bar';
import BasketItem from './BasketItem'
import "../css/basket.min.css"
const session = axios.create({
 withCredentials: true
});
const configAxios = {
 headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,

  },
};
const Basket = props => {
 const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
 const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);
 const [error, setError] = useState('');
 const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {

     const data = {
         url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/22/",
         quantity: 1,
     }
     session.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/basket/add-product/',data)
     .then(res =>{
         console.log(res.data)
         console.log("Cookies are ", document.cookie)
     })
     session.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/basket/add-product/',data)
     .then(res =>{
         console.log(res.data)
         console.log("Cookies are ", document.cookie)
     })},[])
```

And this is results of my requests
[image: First request]

[image: Second request]

So if you can see sessionid values are different instead of being the same and its provide to 401 error.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I also have the same problem on Django 1.11: for every request, I get a response with a `Set-Cookie` that replaces the `sessionId` with a new one. Which makes `vary_on_cookie` useless because the cookie is always different.

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene, same problem for me. did you find a solution?

Comment: @Asif Biswas yes, one of my middlewares was setting some data on the session at every request, causing it to change and the cookie was been set again.